# Run batch file in over 100 subfolders of a parent directory

Tags: batch, batch-file, script, files-folders, autocad

I have to specify that am literally 3 days into scripting and batching. I have a hard time understanding many functions and there variations.

The batch script below should allow me to export ***.shp*** files from AutoCAD Map 3D and create ***input*** folders in each individual folder that contains the ***.dwg*** files processed in AutoCAD. Then the shapefiles are moved in the renamed folder.
My script works only if all the dwg file are in one folder where the ***.bat*** and ***.scr*** file are located.

In short I want to create a script that looks in all subfolders from directory ***D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run*** and exports all the ***.shp*** files inside the ***input*** folder.

```
for %%f in (D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\*.dwg) do ("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2023\acad.exe" %%f /b D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\mapexport.scr
mkdir "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\input"
rename "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\input" "%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\cz_proiectata*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\aerian*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\subteran*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\ax_drum*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\cabinete*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\cam_proiectate*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\stalpi_proiectati*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
move "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\stalpi_existenti*.*" "D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\%%~nf_input"
timeout 5 >nul
)
del D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\*bak
```

I also want to know what is the difference between the following versions of scripts:

```
for %%f in (D:\AutoRunLisp_setup\Run\*.dwg)

for %%f in (*.dwg)

for %%f in (*.*)
```

And please recommend other similar examples found in Stack Exchange.

Excuse my bad English.

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && cd /d "D:\"

set "_run_acad=start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2023\acad.exe""
set "_string_name=cz_proiectata,aerian,subteran,ax_drum,cabinete,cam_proiectate,stalpi_proiectati,stalpi_existenti"

for /r /d %%# in (.)do for %%i in ("%%~f#\*.dwg")do cd /d "%%~dpi" && (
    2>nul md .\"%%~ni_input" & %_run_acad% "%%~fi" /b .\mapexport.scr
    for %%G in (%_string_name%) do move .\"%%~G*.*" .\"%%~ni_input" )

del /q .\"*.bak" & endlocal
```

---

This is a suggestion that includes the subfolders present in **`D:\`**

There is no example of your folder tree to be able to suggest something that includes your subfolders in a precise location, so this is a suggestion for the entire drive.

Try editing your question and adding a path that points where your substantives should be reached, so an edit will be added as soon as possible on a timely basis.

---

Below is a suggestion version that just echoes the actions/commands, you can try to run it first and check where it meets and where a command could possibly be wrong that way:

**`D:\>Run_Echo.bat >"%temp%\Out_log.txt" & "%temp%\Out_log.txt"`**

---

```bath
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && cd /d "D:\"

set "_run_acad=start "" /wait "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2023\acad.exe""
set "_string_name=cz_proiectata,aerian,subteran,ax_drum,cabinete,cam_proiectate,stalpi_proiectati,stalpi_existenti"

for /r /d %%# in (.)do for %%i in ("%%~f#\*.dwg")do cd /d "%%~dpi" && (
    2>nul echo\md .\"%%~ni_input" & echo\%_run_acad% "%%~fi" /b .\mapexport.scr
    for %%G in (%_string_name%) do echo\move .\"%%~G*.*" .\"%%~ni_input" )

echo\ del /q .\"*.bak" & endlocal
```

---

See linked explanatory content

> See linked explanatory content:
> *[I also want to know what is the difference between the following versions of scripts:](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)*